# Word count on Java

Tags: java, for-loop

How can I count the words of a sentence given as string? We are allowed  to use only the following: `for` loops, `if` statemant, `while`, `charAt`, `length()`.

I wrote this code:

```
public static int getWordCount()
{
  String data = "bla bla bla bla";
  int Count = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++)
  {
    if (data.charAt(i) != ' ')
    Count ++;
  }
  return Count;
}
```

But it counts only the letters and not the words.

Comment: You are specifically ignoring spaces with `!= ' '`. Perhaps you should only include spaces with `== ' '`

Comment: variables like `count` should be in camelCase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a suggestion: Count the number of `' '` and add 1?

Example:

```
"bla bla bla bla"
    1   2   3      : 3 + 1   = 4

"hello"
                   : 0 + 1   = 1
```

---

If you want to get fancy you could keep a boolean variable named something like `lastWasSpace`, set it to true when running into a space, setting it to false when you run into a non-space character. If you only increment the `Count` when `lastWasSpace` is false, you'll be able to handle strings with multiple consecutive spaces as well.

```
             "bla    bla      bla"
                 1      2             : 2 + 1 = 3
lastWasSpace: FFFFTTTFFFFTTTTTFFFF
```

Comment: What happen if there are two word separated by multiple spaces?

Comment: Updated my answer in that regard.

Comment: @Drahakar rights.. because they wrote on the question that we need take into consideration that maybe are separated by multiple (or more) spaces

Comment: Oh thank you. how i cant to see that things in the test.. i'm lossing all my logical thinking... and that simple question..

Comment: Finally, i failed to do that. if the string have more then one space - it's counted it. i tried all. Bugger ! where i wrong. today i have repeat test and i cant to think !

Comment: How about ""?  That would also yield 1 as the result.

Comment: Ah, good point. While we're on the subject of corner cases, I think `" a "` would be problematic too. I'll leave these cases as exercises ;-)

Comment: If `length` is allowed, as stated in the OP, you simply check `if var.length() > 0` at the beginning, to ensure there is at least something. You would also have to start with `lastWasSpace` as true, until proven otherwise, to prevent a white-space only string messing you up.

Answer (score 2):

the given code would indeed count letters and not words. You may want to change the condition to:

```
if (data.charAt(i) == ' ')
```

this means, if you find a space, this would mark the beginning of the next word. Also, the last word will not be counted so you should return `Count+1` instead of `Count`.

There are several assumptions I made here:

> 1. There will be exactly one space in between words.
> 2. There will not be any leading or trailing spaces.

To consider multiple spaces between words, you would need to modify the code a little. Instead of checking if a character is space, check to see if a character is non-space and the previous character was either a space or no character for the case of first word. This would also handle leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
String ss =  "   leading spaces in string  ";
String[] sa = ss.trim().split("\\w+");
System.out.println(sa.length);
```

Note the use of `trim` to handle surrounding whitespace.

Comment: Nice, but we cant use split. thank you anyway ! i learned somthing :)

Comment: Later the OP will have special cases like handling dots, commas and other special characters. Using Regex is the way to go. +1

Comment: "cant use split" part was less evident from the question :-).

Comment: -1 because it doesn't count the number of words. How many words are there in this sentence? `"How many words are there in this sentence?".split("\\w+").length` gives 9, and there are only 8.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "This is a Test";
        int wordCount = 1;
        int charCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            if (data.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                wordCount++;
            } else {
                charCount++;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("wordCount = " + wordCount);
        System.out.println("charCount = " + charCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for count the words in the line,

```
            int index = 0;
            int numWords =0;
            boolean prevwhitespace = true;
            String line = "bla bla bla bla";
            while(index < line.length())
            {
                char c = line.charAt(index++);
                boolean currwhitespace = Character.isWhitespace(c);
                if(prevwhitespace && !currwhitespace)
                {
                    numWords++;
                }
                prevwhitespace= currwhitespace;
            }
           System.out.println("no. of words in the line :: " +numWords);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
public static int getWordCount() {
  String data = "bla bla bla bla";
  String[] arr = data.split(" ");
  return arr.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
String s = "Aljohani Abdallah";
int counter = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == ' ' && s.charAt(i + 1) != ' ')
        counter++;
}
if (s == " ")
    counter = 0;
System.out.println(counter);
```

this code above here is count number of words in String so the first thing I have to know is length of the string and then we do if condition, if i was in index equals space at the same time must the letter after space not equal space the add 1 to counter

the end if the String was empty the counter should be zero.

Answer (score -2):

```
String str = "  Hello there   my name     is   Bill    ";
str = str.trim();
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    if(str.charAt(i) == ' ' && str.charAt(i-1) != ' ') {
        count++;
    }
}

System.out.println(count+1);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please explain your code? Thank you for contributing!